# evaluating a textual equation into a number

Tags: powerbi, m

AS a newbie to m I still can't get my head around it. Here is the query I have. It's gone through a number of steps to get to the below. How do I use Expression.Evaluate against the whole query against the column EntryFee, which for the sake of simplicity the query is called #"Nearly There".  I want to Evaluate the entire column Entry Fee. To reiterate it needs to be done in Power Query "M"

Snapshot of table/query

[image: snapshot of query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add a new custom column with the code

```
Expression.Evaluate([Entry Fee])
```

or do a column transformation

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Nearly There", {{"Entry Fee", Expression.Evaluate, type number}})
```

To generate this step, you can select the column and then Transform tab > Format > Trim and then replace `Text.Trim` with `Expression.Evaluate` in the generated code.

Comment: URA gem, by that one clear explanation, I now know how to employ so many other functions. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, I use that second one a lot. Don't forget to accept the answer if it is indeed resolved.